# odoo duplicate company get error

Tags: odoo-8

I override the copy and create function of res.company as follow.

```
def copy(self, cr, uid, id, default=None, context=None):
        self.duplicate = True
        old_rc = self.browse(cr, uid, [id], context=context)[0]

        company_name = self.read(cr, uid, [id], ['name'])[0]['name']
        default.update({'name': _('%s (copy)')% company_name})
        if old_rc.custom_company_code:
            default.update({'custom_company_code': old_rc.custom_company_code + "-Copy"})
        else:
            default.update({'custom_company_code': old_rc.name + "-Copy"})
        return super(ResCompany, self).copy(cr, uid, id, default, context=context)

def create(self, cr, uid, vals, context=None):
        if vals.get('name', False):
            temp_name = vals.get('name', False)
            temp_name = temp_name.replace('\'', '"')
            cr.execute("SELECT id FROM res_company WHERE lower(name)=lower(E'" + temp_name + "')")
            uniq_comps = set(id[0] for id in cr.fetchall())
            if len(uniq_comps) > 0:
                raise UserError(_("Name must be unique for company '%s'.") % (vals.get('name', False),))

        if not vals.get('custom_company_code', False):
            vals['custom_company_code'] = self.pool.get('ir.sequence').next_by_code(cr, uid, 'res_company_code_sequence') or '/'

        if vals.get('custom_company_code', False):
            vals['custom_company_code'] = vals.get('custom_company_code', '').upper()
        if not vals.get('name', False) or vals.get('partner_id', False):
            self.cache_restart(cr)
        return super(ResCompany, self).create(cr, uid, vals, context=context)
```

custom_company_code is user_requirement. But when I click the "Duplicate" at "More", I got the

> Odoo Warning - Validation Error
>
> The company name must be unique !

when I check the log, I got the following line before popup the above error

> openerp.sql_db: bad query: UPDATE "res_company" SET "name"='My
>   Company' WHERE id = 4

How do I solve the problem!!

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem. Because of partner_id

**default.update({'partner_id': False})**

example

```
def copy(self, cr, uid, id, default=None, context=None):
        company_name = self.read(cr, uid, [id], ['name'])[0]['name']
        default.update({'name': _('%s-Copy')% company_name})
        default.update({'partner_id': False})
        return super(res_company, self).copy(cr, uid, id, default, context=context)
```